# Ruby equivalent to Python's help()?

Tags: python, ruby

When working in interactive Python, I tend to rely on the built-in `help()` function to tell me what something expects and/or returns, and print out any documentation that might help me. Is there a Ruby equivalent to this function?

I'm looking for something I could use in irb. For example, in interactive Python I could type:

```
>>> help(1)
```

which would then print

```
Help on int object:

class int(object)  |  int(x[, base])
-> integer  |    |  

Convert a string or number to an integer, if possible. A ...
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468421/ruby-equivalent-of-pythons-dir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `ri` from within `irb`. I'd recommend the [wirble gem](https://github.com/pablotron/wirble) as an easy way to set this up.

Comment: ok, I think this will work. I can get the doc for the class with
"Object.ri variable.class" and I can get the method doc with "Object.ri variable.class.to_s + ".method". Thanks

Comment: I type `ri String` and it says "Nothing known about String".

Comment: Do you know if wirble still works? (and is up to date?) (the link is broken)

Answer (score 9):

It's now late 2014 and here's the two ways to get the Python `help()` *similarity, as long as you have the [Ruby Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13886612/2062384) installed:

1. From inside `irb`, You can call the `help` method with a string describing what you're looking for.

   Example 1: `help 'Array'` for the Array class
   Example 2: `help 'Array#each'` for the `Array` class `each` method.
2. From the command line, *outside* of `irb`, you can use the `ri` program:

   Example 1: `ri 'Array'` for the Array class
   Example 2: `ri 'Array#each'` for the `Array` class `each` method.

* Not quite as good as Python's, but still better than nothing

Answer (score 1):

For quick shell access to ruby documentation, just type ri followed by the method you're wanting to learn more about (from your shell).

For example:

`ri puts`

This must be fired up in your shell, not your irb (interactive ruby environment)

If you're in your irb environment, then another way, is to simply type help followed by the method you want to learn more about as follows:

```
help puts
```

However, this assumes that you have configured your Ruby environment correctly for that (help) to work properly within irb.  I usually just have another shell open, and just use the ri directly for quick access when I'm in doubt about a certain method or arguments to a method.