# Why doesn't `ri String#upcase` work but `ri upcase` does?

Tags: ruby, ri

I can do `ri upcase` to see documentation:

```
$ ri upcase
...lots of output...
```

and I should be able to do `ri String#upcase`, but that gives me:

```
$ ri String#upcase
Nothing known about String#upcase
$ ri 'String#upcase'
Nothing known about String#upcase
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
```

Why can't I get `String#upcase` to work? I would generally like to be able to do `ri class#method`.

Comment: "ri String#upcase" works in Ruby 1.9.3, verified.

Comment: sawa, I copied and pasted your command into my shell and got this:  `$ ri String#upcase
Nothing known about String#upcase
durrantm.../ruby$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
durrantm.../ruby$ `

Comment: btw I am on Ubuntu and this is a real issue.  Not sure why I'm getting close votes for a real issue I am experiencing :)

Comment: Ubuntu version? I am on 11.10

Comment: Not working for me, so don't feel bad @MichaelDurrant :)  Glad I don't use ri!

Comment: Great!  not just me!  :)

Comment: Nick - are you on Ubuntu 11 or 12?

Comment: Oh, I use 13.04, forgot it. Not 12.10. Doesn't quotes works for you?

Comment: No, quotes didn't work for me (either single or double).  Maybe it's zsh vs bash?

Comment: installed zsh and that wasn't it.

Comment: Alternatively, ri upcase or ri .upcase

Comment: So the current candidate for this is being on Ubuntu 11.10 which is probably not the heart of the issue

Comment: Alternatively, keep a console always open when working. Actually I never use `ri` on command line, all on console.

Comment: Probably some ri doc is missing. Try the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178900/how-do-i-install-the-ruby-ri-documentation