# How to install Ruby ri documentation for Ruby v2.1.7

Tags: ruby, ri

Can somebody point me to how I can install the ri documentation for v2.1.7?

I tried "[How do I install the Ruby ri documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178900/how-do-i-install-the-ruby-ri-documentation)" with no luck.

I would prefer installing ri so that I can lookup specific methods in a class directly without opening the help file.

Also, I had no luck with the following:

```
C:\Users\ram\ruby>gem install rdoc-data
Fetching: rdoc-data-4.0.1.gem (100%)
rdoc-data is only required for C ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.1.

rdoc-data is required for JRuby.

To install ri data for RDoc 4.0+ run:

  rdoc-data --install

Successfully installed rdoc-data-4.0.1
Parsing documentation for rdoc-data-4.0.1
Installing ri documentation for rdoc-data-4.0.1
Done installing documentation for rdoc-data after 1 seconds
1 gem installed

C:\Users\ram\ruby>ri Array
Nothing known about Array

C:\Users\ram\ruby>rdoc-data --install
Your ruby version 2.1.7 is not supported, only 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 2.0.0
```

It seems that for v2.1.7 something else is required.

Note this is for Windows. I want to do it natively without using VM/Cygwin, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As your error message indicates, `rdoc-data` doesn't support `ruby 2.1.7`.

If you're using RVM, try:

```
rvm docs generate
```

Be patient, it takes several minutes to install the documentation.

If you want the ri documentation installed by default for all gem installations, check your gem config file `~/.gemrc` to see if you have defaults set up that excludes documentation. Remove any and all of the following:

```
install: --no-rdoc --no-ri 
update: --no-rdoc --no-ri
install: --no-document
update: --no-document
gem: --no-document
```

I believe gems install documentation by default. If not, add this to the gem config file

```
gem: --ri
```

---

Since you're on Windows, you can install Cygwin on your Windows machine and then install RVM using Cygwin. Or, you can download the rdocs source files http://ruby-doc.org/downloads/ and extract them to your Ruby docs folder `/Users/userprofile/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/doc/`.
I did a cursory glance, and didn't see `ruby 2.1.7`; it goes straight from `2.1.6` to `2.2.0`. You can dump `2.1.6` in the `ruby-2.1.7/doc/` folder or update your Ruby version to one that is supported.

Comment: @zooter I updated my answer based on your Windows OS. You may want to add that info to your question in case someone else has something to add.