# How do I install ri documentation in JRuby?

Tags: jruby, rdoc, ri

I installed JRuby 9.2.11.1 on a Windows system.
After the installation has successfully completed, no ri documentation for core/stdlib is present.
For instance:

```
C:\>ri Array
Nothing known about Array
```

I tried this solution [How do I install the Ruby ri documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178900/how-do-i-install-the-ruby-ri-documentation/45741781#45741781) (admittedly, for Ruby Installer, not JRuby) to no avail. After trying to run `rdoc --all --ri` I obtain the following error message:

```
Before reporting this, could you check that the file you're documenting
has proper syntax:

  C:/jruby-9.2.11.1/bin/jruby.exe -c NEWS

RDoc is not a full Ruby parser and will fail when fed invalid ruby programs.

The internal error was:

        (NameError) undefined local variable or method `console' for IO:Class
Did you mean?  console_size
```

(Note: installed RDoc gem version is 6.1.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out: it seems that the JRuby version of `io/console` does not work well with the Windows Command prompt: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/lib/ruby/stdlib/io/console/jruby.rb.

A solution is, for example, to issue the `rdoc --all --ri` command within a [Windows Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win) rather than a Command prompt.