# Does Ruby have a "dir" method, similar to Python?

Tags: python, ruby

I'm coming to Ruby from Python, and I'm wondering if Ruby has some equivalent of `dir()` in Python that I can use within the IRB.  I was looking at this SO thread linked below, where it appears to not be the case, but it's a 6 year old post so I was trying to find out if anything had changed since then.

[Ruby Equivalent of Python dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468421/ruby-equivalent-of-pythons-dir)

`objects.methods.sort` is nice, but I want to see things like instance/class variables on an object as well (really everything publicly available in the namespace), not just methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is fairly popular gem [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), which has method called `ls` that can provide you I believe with something, similar to the `dir` in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby can tell you the methods: `obj.methods`.

There's also:
`#public_methods, #instance_methods, #private_methods, etc.`

Ruby can tell you the instance variables `#instance_variables`.
Ruby can't tell you the documentation; there's no docstring like there
is in Python. There are some enhancements to irb available that give
an ri command from within irb.